# jQuery Widget . How to take the current modifiable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, cart

I have a basket with goods. When you change the amount of goods in the basket I have to pass this very field that has changed. How do I submit the current editable field?

```js
define([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui' ], function($) {
  "use strict";
  $.widget('web4pro.cart', {
    options: {
      triggerEvent: 'change',
      controller: 'http://developer.loc/web4pro_cart/query/custom',
      qty: '[data-role="cart-item-qty"]'
    },
    _create: function() {
      this._bind();
    },
    _bind: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.element.on(self.options.triggerEvent, function() {
        self._ajaxSubmit();
      });
    },
    _ajaxSubmit: function() {
      //jQuery(this.options.qty).on('change', function () {
      console.log(this.element.find(this.options.qty).on('change', this._updateOrderHandler).val());
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://developer.loc/web4pro_cart/query/custom',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'qty=' + jQuery('[data-role="cart-item-qty"]').val(),
        success: function(res) {
          alert('ajax send');
          console.log('ajax success');
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        }
      });
      //});
    },
    _updateOrderHandler: function() {
      $(this).trigger('change');
    }
  });
  return $.web4pro.cart;
});
```

Comment: When do you want to submit the data? Change, keydown, blur? Do you need any validation beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution.**

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui'
    ], function($) {
        "use strict";
        $.widget('NameSpace.widget', {
            options: {
                triggerEvent: 'change',
                controller: 'frontName/query/custom',
                qty: '[data-role="cart-item-qty"]',
                itemId: '.action.action-edit'
            },

            _create: function() {
                this._bind();
            },

            _bind: function() {
                var self = this;
                    self._ajaxSubmit();

            },

            _ajaxSubmit: function() {
                jQuery(this.options.qty).on('change', function () {
                    var that = this;
                   // here we need to refer to the context of jQuery
                    var url = domine + 'NameSpace_widget/query/custom';
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: //your data,
                        success: function(res) {
                            // your code
                        }
                    });
                });
            },

            _updateOrderHandler: function () {
                $(this).trigger('change');
            }
        });
        return $.NameSpace.widget;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onBlur method and call an update function.